# Accessing a textfield as a subview of UITableCell which is part of a viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios

i have a viewcontroller which has a table view. this tableView has a custom tableview cell which has a UITextField. i would like to manipulate the UITextField from within the viecontroller. how would i do that?

also, another question. what does it mean when using the following syntax

```
id<SomeDelegate> name;?
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If your view controller is a sub class of UITableViewController, you can do this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellAtIndexPath:(pass indexpath)];
```

and then manipulate the cell

If it is a custom cell

You can create member variables for

```
UITextField *mytextfield
```

at class level and store their references while constructing the cell, to manipulate them later

Comment: i see. what about if i wanted to access the UItextfields delegate methods? i.e handling keyboard show/hide events?

Comment: For that you need to set the current Controller inherit from UITextField delegate and then assign mytextfield.delegate = self while constructing.

Comment: You can set it directly to your cell UITextField delegate, and add the UITextField delegate methods to your ViewController